How to set proper alignment in CI 3 Dompdf?
In CI 3 I am using dompdf library but alignment working fine in normal HTML but it is not working in pdf. Here is screenshot. Is there any way to set alignment properly in pdf because I need to use this code two place.

In window.print
In generating pdf using dompdf



Here is my HTML code
<?php
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_parts = explode('/', $current_url);
$type = end($url_parts);
?>
<html><head>
    <title>Patient History</title>
    <style>
        td, th {
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head><body>
        <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 5px!important"><h2><?php echo ucfirst($branch_detail['user_name']);?></h2></div>
        <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 5px!important">
            <p>
                <?php echo $company_data['address'];?><br>
                Phone No.(s) :+91<?php echo $company_data['contact_no']; ?><br>
                Email ID. :<?php echo $company_data['email']; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <hr style="widht:100%" />
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1px">
                  <?php
                    if(!empty($self_opd_collection_list)){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th> OPD No.</th>
                        <th> Date </th>
                        <th> Doctor </th>
                        <th> Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    foreach($self_opd_collection_list as $patients) {?>
                          <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $patients->number; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($patients->date)); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $patients->doctor_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $patients->amount; ?></td>
                          </tr>
                  <?php
                    }
                    }
                    if(!empty($self_billing_collection_list)){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Bill No.</th>
                        <th> Date </th>
                        <th> Particular </th>
                        <th> Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $i=1;
                    foreach($self_billing_collection_list as $patients)
                    {?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $patients->number; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($patients->date)); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $patients->particulars; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $patients->amount; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                    $i++;   
                    }
                    }
                        
                    if(!empty($self_ipd_collection_list)){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th> IPD No.</th>
                        <th> Date </th>
                        <th> Doctor </th>
                        <th> Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $i=1;
                    foreach($self_ipd_collection_list as $patients)
                    {?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $patients->number; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($patients->date)); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $patients->doctor_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $patients->amount; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                    $i++;   
                    }
                    }
                    ?> 
                </table>
        </div>
</body></html>

And here is my php code
$users_data = $this->session->userdata('auth_users');
        $this->load->model('opd_billing/opd_billing_model','opd_billing');
        $data['branch_detail']=$users_data;
        $data['company_data']=$this->session->userdata('company_data');
        if($type == 'all'){
            $data['self_opd_collection_list'] = $this->patient->get_patient_history_datatables($id,'11',$branch_id);
            $data['self_billing_collection_list'] = $this->patient->get_patient_history_datatables($id,'2',$branch_id);
            foreach($data['self_billing_collection_list'] as $value) {
                $get_particulars= $this->opd_billing->get_billed_particular_list($value->id);
                $paticulars_new=array();
                foreach($get_particulars as $particulars){
                    $paticulars_new[]=$particulars['particulars'];

                }
                $value->particulars = implode(',', $paticulars_new);
            }
            $data['self_ipd_collection_list'] = $this->patient->get_patient_history_datatables($id,'4',$branch_id);
        }else{
            $data['patient_list'] = $this->patient->get_patient_history_datatables($id,$type,$branch_id);                
        }
            // echo"<pre>";print_r($data);die;
        $this->load->view('patient/print_patient_history',$data);
        $html = $this->output->get_output();
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $this->pdf->load_html($html);
        $this->pdf->render();
        $this->pdf->stream("patient_history_".time().".pdf");

